# How to select dropDown options when is not with <Select> tag with Selenium in Python

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Would like to select the date in the following URL (Yellow highlighted):

https://www.hkex.com.hk/mutual-market/stock-connect/statistics/historical-daily?sc_lang=en-hk#select4=3&select5=1&select3=0&select1=1&select2=6

[image]

And when inspecting the HTML code, I couldn't find any "select" tag as below:
[image]

My code:

```html
chrome_options  =   Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1920,1080")
driver=webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path=r'/Users/Woodylin/Desktop/Python Learnings/chromedriver')
#driver=webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path=r'C:/Users/wolin/Desktop/Python/chromedriver.exe')

url1 = 'https://www.hkex.com.hk/Mutual-Market/Stock-Connect/Statistics/Historical-Daily?sc_lang=zh-HK#select4=2&select5=1&select3=0&select1=1&select2=6' #滬港通 

driver.get(url1)
sleep(3)
ele_date          =    driver.find_element_by_id('select-target-date') #Target Date
DropDown1         =   Select(ele_date)
DropDown1.select_by_visible_text('7')
```

So how could I set the select the option?

***Current Update:***

Found that if I use the following XPATH will select "5th" day

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='mainform']/div[8]/main/section/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[**5**]/a").click()
```

**#However, if I use the command below to select "31st" day, it returns below error:**

```
Err msg: selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='mainform']/div[8]/main/section/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[**31**]/a").click()
```

Comment: found that if I use the following XPATH can choose :
#Below command will select "5th" day
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='mainform']/div[8]/main/section/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[5]/a").click()

#However, if I use the following command to choose "31st" day, it returns below error:
Err msg: selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='mainform']/div[8]/main/section/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[31]/a").click()

Comment: have you tried with `//a[@class='select-target-date'][.='31']? Can you please share the div that contains all the dates, so that we can help you with the correct Xpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**`Select`**](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.select.html) Docs:

> Constructor. A check is made that the given element is, indeed, a SELECT tag.......

Your target element isn't `SELECT` tag. So you can't use `Select`

Try another approach with css selector. You need click first the date element to make dropdown bring up the date list, and before click element target, use `location_once_scrolled_into_view` first.

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.csm-dailystat-day-selection').click()
target_date = '7'
ele_date = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.csm-dailystat-day-selection div[data-value="{}"]'.format(target_date))
ele_date.location_once_scrolled_into_view
ele_date.click()
```

Comment: So if I do the same for the target_month, it occur the error below:
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <div class="select-group csm-dailystat-month-selection">...</div> is not clickable at point (744, 24). Other element would receive the click: <a href="#" class="main-menu__link " target="_self" title="...">服務</a>

May I know how I can get the target Month also? Would I need to use 'expected_conditions' to click other element after ?

Comment: @Woody For `target_month` use this selector `div.csm-dailystat-month-selection`